Tell cmake not to use -Wl,-Bdynamic?
I want to make a static exe, I've added "-static" to the target_link_libraries(), it almost does it, but it uses -Wl,-Bdynamic at the end of its command:
$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/c++  [...snip...] -static ../libirc/libirc.a -lboost_program_options -lboost_log_setup ../libutil/libutil.a -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lboost_thread -Wl,-Bstatic -lircclient -lssl -lcrypto -Wl,-Bdynamic 

If I manually take the -Wl,-Bdynamic off the end it works, it seems like that leads the linker to think the final exe should be static. How do I convince cmake otherwise?

Are you sure that all libraries you link with are static? And can you pleased [edit] your question to show us your CMakeLists.txt file?

Given the command succeeds without the last -Wl,-Bdynamic they must be, right? Will try adding my cmake when I can

Instead of manually adding -static, you are better to manipulate LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC and LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC target properties, like in that answer.
